# Enable cors for one route while keep it same for others

Tags: node.js, express, axios, cors

I've an express app and this is how I've configured it

```
// app.js file
const corsConfig = { origin: process.env.FRONT_END }
app.use(cors(corsConfig));
app.options("*", cors(corsConfig));

app.use("/api/v1/users", userRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/projects", projectRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/leads", leadRouter);


// in leadRouter.js file
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", authController.protect, leadController.getLeads);
router.options("/:projectId", cors({origin: true}));
router.post("/:projectId", cors({origin: true}), leadController.createLead);
```

I want to open `/api/v1/leads/:projectId` to everyone while keep other routes as configured before. But my current configuration is not working and I'm getting preflight cors error when post on `api/v1/leads/:projectId`

In the frontend I'm using axios and it may set 'authorization' header when sending the request.
Any explanation why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// This route will allow cross-origin requests for everyone
router.options("/:projectId", (req, res) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.status(200).send();
});

router.get("/", authController.protect, leadController.getLeads);

// No need to use cors middleware for the route below, as we already set the headers in the options route.
router.post("/:projectId", leadController.createLead);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: But I do want to set cors settings for get('/") routes just not for post(/:projectId")

Comment: You shouldn't encourage people to implement CORS manually. Instead, a CORS middleware library should be used. Express has one.